# Nondimensionalize a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The equation I have is $\frac{dy}{dx}=a\frac{\sin (bx)}{k+\sin (bx)}-cy$. I am asked to nondimensionize it. I found out that in this case, I do not need to know the dimensions of x or y. I can just let $[x]=X$ and $[y]=Y$ and try to nondimensionlize it this way. Also, this is not a polynomial equation so it is transcendental. So I also know the output is dimensionless. Now that I have this information, what is the next step here?

Comment: So $x$ and $y$ must have the same dimensions, and $a$ is a pure number, while $[c]=Y^{-1}$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro It can work out different ways; all that must happen is that $[x][a]/[y]$, $[x][c]$, $[b][x]$ and $[k]$ need to all be dimensionless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $x = X\cdot u$, $y= Y\cdot v(u)$. You know $dy/dx = Y(dv/du)(du/dx) = (Y/X)dv/du$, so
\begin{equation}
(Y/X)v'(u) = a\frac{\sin(bXu)}{k + \sin(bXu)} - Ycv(u).
\end{equation}
Dividing through you get
\begin{equation}
v'(u) = \frac{Xa}{Y}\frac{\sin(bXu)}{k + \sin(bXu)} - Xcv(u).
\end{equation}

Comment: You have a minor error, you didn't cancel $Y/Y$ in the second term.

Comment: Thanks @Ian for pointing that out … fixed!

Comment: Is there a way to donate points?